# nfc on samsung nexus s

Tags: android, nfc, nexus-s

I have nexus s mobile with me. I am working with the smartcard apps on android. As i surffing over net, I came to know that nexus s mobile is able to read the smartcard tags. When i tried to connect the smartcards which i  have , I am unable to get the tag information and i have no Response. why is that not connected with nexus s . All i need to know is, Is there any specific needs the smartcards should satisfy to connect with nexus s ??  Or what kind of tags we can connect with nexus s mobile.

Can anyone pls give me your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can read all the tag types specified by [TagTechnology](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/package-summary.html) with the Nexus S. If you can not read the Tag it could be a matter of malformed content, invalid authentication Keys (in case you are reading protected Tag such as a Mifare Classic or a Mifare Desfire), etc.

Instead of using default Tag read application, I recommend you the [NFC Tag Info from NXP](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite) application. It gives you much more information about the underlying specification of the read tag.